# FreeRTOS Task Notification

Tags: message-queue, producer-consumer, multitasking, freertos

Quick Architecture Question...

There are 4 producers and 1 consumer for a message queue. Each of the 4 producers have their own task and are there to service incoming data from 4 specific hardware communications references.

Should the Consumer task have a wait function for each one or can I use task notification where each task notifies the Consumer that a message has arrived?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just setup the consumer task to wait on the queue. When there is data in the queue from any of the producers it will wake up and you can process the data.

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate the answer. I have other questions but I will get started and then post any other questions.